# Trouble handling communication between classes

Tags: c++, class, object, communication

I'm working on a problem where an entire application's language needs to change every time a user specifies a new language on the screen. The function to recognize that a new language has been selected is located in one of the application's classes, Class3. I need some way to notify one of my objects that the language change has occurred. What's tricky is that this object is defined in Class1, and initialized in a different class (Class2), and needs to be updated or notified by Class3.  Here is the basic layout:

ObjectA is defined in Class1.
ObjectA is initialized in Class2.
ObjectA needs to be accessed whenever the input language changes in Class3.

How should I approach the communication between all these classes? I'm kind of confused and any guidance would help. Sorry if this post was confusing!!

Comment: Look into the Observer pattern.

Comment: Besides design patterns etc. What you need is `Object3` to has a reference or pointer to `ObjectA`. Thus, when language change is done in by `Object3` at the same time `ObjectA` is updated via this reference/pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that in case of language dependence, you might have a couple of objects that are to be updated.

I'd suggest an architecture where all language dependent objects inherit some base class (up to you to see if simple inheritance is sufficient or multiple inheritence would be necessary).  A virtual function then would allow for tailored language actions when necessary.

The base class would maintain a list of all objects created and deleted, and provide a refresh mecanism to change language.  Something like:

```
class LSensitive {
private: 
    static list<LSensitive*> l;  // all language dependent objects 
protected: 
    virtual void doChangeLanguage(string new_language) = 0;  
                   /* derived class change labels, units, etc... */
public:
    static void changeAll(string new_language) // call this when you want to change !
        { for (auto i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++)
                (*i)->doChangeLanguage(new_language); 
        }
    LSensitive()
        { l.push_front(this); }
    virtual ~LSensitive() 
        {   l.remove(this); }
};
```

Your derived class would then tailor language change code like here:

```
class Class0 : public LSensitive {
private: 
    static int unique_id;
    int myid; 
public: 
    Class0() : myid(unique_id++) {};
    ~Class0() {};
    void doChangeLanguage(string new_language)  // implement the class specific change
    { cout << "Object " << myid << ": change language to " << new_language << endl; };
};
```

When in class3 or anywhere else you notice, it's time to change language, then simply call:

```
LSensitive::changeAll(new_language);
```

The big advantage, is that wherever you create or intialise your language dependent objects, this code would find them and update them.